# group by field and count mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have [this table](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A9J2WSB7xJQ) and this query:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        $toLower: "$firm.status"
      },
      count: {
        $sum: 1
      }
    }
  }
])
```

The result I want to to obtain is:

```
{
    "incomplete": 1,
    "pending": 2,
    "complete": 1
}
```

but the result I obtain is:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "incomplete",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "complete",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "_id": "pending",
    "count": 2
  }
]
```

How can I modify my query in order to obtain what I want? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Still have no idea how to adapt , @Fanpark because I am new to mongo, so you didn't help at all with the 'duplicate'. And btw, I don't think the questions are the same.

Comment: Add below stage. `{ "$group": {
    "_id": null,
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "k": "$_id",
        "v": "$count"
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$replaceRoot": {
    "newRoot": { "$arrayToObject": "$data" }
  }}`. https://mongoplayground.net/p/9uNxZPYD9p4

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand!